# Magento: Role Resources not showing

Tags: magento, acl

I'm having this issue on magento 1.5.1:

The resource role tree is empty ( **web service and permission** )

To find out the error I have:

1. disabled all extension ( moved xml files away from /etc/modules/ ) but this is not fixing.
2. make a diff with original core files. ( files are identical )

So the problem should be at some db level.

I have found this old discussion, but it didn't help me :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21449/

**Update:**

I found out that the empty tree is caused by these code lines:

file: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Tab/Rolesedit.php

```
    $rootArray = $this->_getNodeJson($resources->admin, 1);

    $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(isset($rootArray['children']) ? $rootArray['children'] : array());
```

$json is empty while $rootArray is looks correctly populated ( it contains a ['children'] node )
So the problem starts in jsonEncode() method

Comment: Any error logs in var/ . check your db with magento db repairing tool. fix errors if any db error, then clear cache and check.

Comment: What happens when you check the database table that the resources are stored in?  What happens when you attempt to load the reosurces programatically yourself?

Comment: it looks like resource are corrected loaded at model level

Answer (score 0):

1. disable all extension
2. Crosscheck core file (**/app/code/core**, **/js**, **/lib**, **/app/design/adminhtml**) with a default magento files
   ex. `diff -qrbB magento_origina/js/ YOUR_MAGE_PROJECT/js/`
3. revert any changes
4. clear cache ( also if you have disabled it, backend will continue to be cached )
5. check if it is fixed
6. isolate the problem and fix it

-> in this particular situation the problem was related to some mods in the file /js/ext-tree-checkbox.js